# jQuery - addClass to multiple items, when one of the items is var

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to `addClass` to multiple items simultaneously, when one of the items is variable?

**Example:**

```
var id = '#id-2';
$('#id-1', id).addClass("input--error"); // does not work
```

Comment: `$("#id-1," + id).addClass("input--error");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If part of your string is in a variable, then just use string operations to add the contents of the variable to the rest of your string to create one selector string:

```
var id = '#id-2';
$('#id-1, ' + id).addClass("input--error");
```